# Which is the appropriate way to set default value for python class?

Tags: python, class

What is the difference between this -->

```
class Battery:
    def __init__(self):
        self.battery = 70
    def batteryInfo(self):
        print(f"This car has {self.battery}mAh battery.")
```

Edit: If I want to change the value of battery, then I can do this -->

```
myTesla = Battery()
myTesla.battery = 90
```

And this -->

```
class Battery:
    def __init__(self, battery=70):
        self.battery = battery
    def batteryInfo(self):
        print(f"This car has {self.battery}mAh battery.")
```

When to use which one of them?

Comment: How would you create a `Battery` object with a `battery` attribute set to something _other_ than 70 in the first case? It doesn't look like 70 is exactly a _default_ value there.

Comment: (Side note 1: the  name of that attribute is fairly confusing. Does a battery have another battery inside it? Maybe `charge` or `capacity` or something would be more appropriate, depending on what that value actually represents.)

Comment: (Side note 2: `batteryInfo()` isn't very idiomatic. `battery_info()` would be more idiomatic. But just `info()` might be even better, since you already have a class named `Battery`. Or `print_info()`, since it is printing something. Or just `info()` with a _`return`_ instead of a `print()`, so the caller can choose what to do with that string. See [the official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: @Chris I can change the value for battery(capacity would be more appropriate name, as you suggested)  by this line of code `myTesla = Battery()
myTesla.battery = 90`  when I'm a creating a new instance. So `self.battery = 70' does work like a  default value.

Comment: Dependency injection is good

Comment: The second option is definitely more idiomatic. But why would you do `myTesla = Battery()`? _Is_ your Tesla a battery? Or does it _have_ a battery? (And, again, `myTesla` isn't very idiomatic: `my_tesla` would probably be better.) I would expect something like `tesla_battery = Battery()` or `my_tesla = Car()`.

Comment: Thank you, from now on I'll definitely keep that in mind. @Chris

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in this case:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.battery = 70
```

the initial value of `battery` is *always* set to 70. If someone initializes a `Battery()`, they cannot set a different value.

Whereas, in this case:

```
def __init__(self, battery=70):
    self.battery = battery
```

someone can set a different initial value if they want. `Battery()` will still create an object with initial `battery` of 70, but `Battery(420)`, for example, will instead have that object have an initial `battery` of 420.

Comment: `self.battery = 70`  I can change this value when creating a new instance like this, `myTesla = Battery() `  `myTesla.battery = 90`  The process is different but in both ways I can change the default value while creating a new instance.

Comment: @MimicMannan, that's _not_ changing the default while creating a new instance. It's creating a new instance with one value and then, afterwards, changing the value. If you want to initialize a value, doing it in the initalizer (`__init__`) is a pretty good idea.

Comment: That's it! Now I understand. Thank you very much. @Chris